# jQuery if div has no any class or div

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

There is a duplicated `<div class="content" data-num="2"></div>` (would be more if click the button more times)which has got nothing in it.
How to check if `content` has nothing in it and get it removed ?

```
if($('.content').children().length == 0)
```

or need to use `each` something like?

```
 $('.content').each(function(i, obj){
     if($('.content').children().length == 0){
        $(this).remove();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:empty` jQuery selector which will select all elements that have no children. See http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/ for details.

Using `:empty` will prevent the need for extra `if` checks in your loop - your delete function only operates on the items to delete ... much more efficient.

So something similar to:

```
$('.content:empty').each(function() {
    //Do your delete, etc here :)
    $(this).remove();
});
```

As suggested by **jfriend00**, the further simplification to just do a delete would be:

```
$('.content:empty').remove();
```

Lots of different ways to tackle it.

Comment: Why not just `$('.content:empty').remove()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 - Even better, updated with your suggestion.

Comment: I don't think your last example is right.  The selector passed to `.remove(selector)` is a filter of the elements in the called jQuery object.  It's not a `.find()` operation that will find children.

Comment: Thanks again. Removed that last option. That will teach me not to edit on my phone, and only going from memory.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a simpler way to do this, but checking the `html()` of each `.content` should work for you. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AQPJ7/)

```
$(".content").each(function(i, obj) {
    if($(this).html() == '') {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've an extra `)` which accidentally closing your `if` clause:

```
if($('.content')).children().length == 0){
// ------------ ^ remove this
```

Otherwise, your code with `each()` should work.